# AS3 Inheritance and Parameters Issues

Tags: actionscript-3, class, inheritance, parameters

I'm having trouble with inheritance, as I have never done it in ActionScript 3.

Please tell me what to do in this situation?

Let's say I have the following class

```
package
{
    public class animal
    {
        var age;
        var amountOfLegs;
        var color;
        public function animal(a,b,c)
        {
            age=a;
            amountOfLegs=b;
            color=c;
        }
    }
 }
```

Then, I wanted to make a derived class

```
package
{
    public class cat extends animal
    {
        var hairType;
        public function cat(a,b,c,d)
        {
            age=a;
            amountOfLegs=b;
            color=c;
            hairType=d;
        }
    }
}
```

Why couldn't I just make the class 'cat' like that?
Someone please explain how I can inherit a class and still satisfy its parameters.
I'm lost.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your cat class, replace:

```
age=a;
amountOfLegs=b;
color=c;
```

with

```
super(a, b, c);
```

this calls the constructor of the base/super class, passing in a,b,c.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `super` to call the parent classes constructor and pass in your values.

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/08/10/understanding-as3-super-statement/

Consider this example

```
//this class defines the properties of all Animals

public class Animal{

    private var _age:int;
    private var _amountOfLegs:int;
    private var _color:String;

    public function Animal(age:int, amountOfLegs:int, color:String){
         _age = age;
         _amountOfLegs = amountOfLegs;
         _color = color;
    }


    public function traceMe():void{

         trace("age: " + _age + "legs: " + _amountOfLegs + " color: " + _color);
    }

}

//this makes a cat
public class Cat extends Animal{
   public function Cat(){
        //going to call the super classes constructor and pass in the details that make a cat
        super(5, 4, "black");
        traceMe(); //will print age: 5 legs: 4 color: black
   }

}
```

More reading:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/

Comment: -1 in AS3 super is called by the run time whether you call it or not. plus you negleted to bring up the actual issue that cat and animal constructors have different amounts of parameters.

Comment: @The_asMan there is no reason cat and animal can't have different constructors. This solution will give the op what he is looking.

Comment: What the op is asking is all about polymorphism which in this case is the ability to type cast Cat and IAnimal. A much better article would be here http://www.developria.com/2009/09/as3-object-oriented-concepts-p.html